Having trouble with Postgres with springboot
I'm having issues running Springboot with any list as when I get rid of the list in the model it works fine. unsure why I can't use a list. having issues with JDBC type on lists.
entity class:
package com.abc.calendar.calendarapi.model;

import lombok.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "calendars") 

public class Calendar {

    @Id
    private String event_id;
    private String company_id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Date start_time;
    private Date end_time;
    private String location;
    private String color;
    private String status;

    private List<String> tags;

    // private List<Participant> participants;

    // private Organizer organizer;
    // private List<Participant> participants;
    // private List<Attachment> attachments;
    // private Recurring recurring;
    // private List<Filter> default_filters;
    // private Map<String, List<String>> user_filters;
   
}

Springboot Console logs
[Tomcat]
  2024-05-23T17:53:23.720-04:00  INFO 19864 --- [calendarapi] [           
  main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
  Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition 
  evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
  2024-05-23T17:53:23.752-04:00 ERROR 19864 --- [calendarapi] [           
  main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting BasicPluralJavaType for array class `[Ljava.lang.String;`, but got `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.internal.StringArrayTypeDescriptor@1f521c69`
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at com.abc.calendar.calendarapi.CalendarapiApplication.main(CalendarapiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting BasicPluralJavaType for array class `[Ljava.lang.String;`, but got `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.internal.StringArrayTypeDescriptor@1f521c69`
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting BasicPluralJavaType for array class `[Ljava.lang.String;`, but got `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.internal.StringArrayTypeDescriptor@1f521c69`  
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiKeyLoadHelper.resolveArrayJdbcMapping(MultiKeyLoadHelper.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiIdEntityLoaderArrayParam.<init>(MultiIdEntityLoaderArrayParam.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.buildMultiIdLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3420) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        ... 20 common frames omitted


Looks like it's issue with your dependency. Which hibernate dependency you're using
